# Spring Web Flows - getInteger() vs getRequiredInteger()

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I got a quick question about the differences between the methods getInteger() and getRequiredInteger().

```
public void foo(RequestContext requestContext){
    MutableAttributeMap flowScope = requestContext.getFlowScope();
    String bar = flowScope.getString("bar","bar"); // (attributeName, defaultValue)
    String baz = flowScope.getRequiredString("baz");
}
```

Is the only difference is that with getInteger(), you can define a default value if the attribute name isn't found within the map?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Spring Web Flow API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/index.html)  difference between both is related to exception throwing -

`getRequiredInteger()` - Returns an integer attribute value in the map, throwing an exception if the attribute is not present and of the correct type.

`getInteger()` - Returns an integer attribute value in the map, returning the default value if no value was found.

Answer (score 0):

No, the primary difference is that getRequiredInteger will throw an exception if the attribute name isn't in the map.